# Regex - remove the last <p> segment of an HTML string

Tags: c#, regex, html-parsing

I have an HTML structure that is being pulled from an RSS feed, and I need to remove part of it, but it is not a standalone part of the stream.

So I have

```
<p>Some Html... </p>
<br />
<p>The p section I want to remove</p>
```

Is there a regex pattern that can do this? find the last `<p>` segment of a given string and chop it out? I am using C# for the Regex.

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure you want to use Regex for this? Actually I think that you should use them only when you need to.

Why don't you consider something like (assuming the HTML is well formed and that there are not nested paragraphs):

```
string html = GetRSS();
int pStartIndex = html.LastIndexOf("<p>");
int pEndIndex = html.LastIndexOf("</p>");
string result = html.Remove(pStartIndex, pEndIndex - pStartIndex + 4);
```

Alternatively you could consider using something more advanced (and maybe appropriate) like HTML Agility Pack or (worse if you are working with bad formed html) the integrated .NET XML parser (**EDIT:** *As svicks says if you choose this solution please make sure that you are working with HTML that is also valid XML*).

Comment: XML parser won't help you even with well-formed and valid HTML. HTML *is not* XML.

Comment: I agree with you but I have just shown him how he could face the problem. Actually I think in this case there isn't a right solution and, even if you are right when you say that HTML is not XML, probably in his case an XML parser works pretty well. I can't stand working following postulates, I prefer instead using something if it fits my requirements and doesn't lead me to other strange problems.

Comment: But that's exactly where using XML parser for HTML will lead you – some strange problems later on. If you're really working with HTML (and not XHTML) and you're not completely sure the HTML will also be a valid XML, you shouldn't use XML parser for working with it.

Comment: I see but I took for granted that he already knew which kind of code he was working with. I will update my answer, thanks :)

Comment: Yes, this works perfectly. And yes, I want to use Regex for this. It is a simple project and it will not be online for more than a few months. I just need to make it work for the moment.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regular expression to replace the last occurrence of the `<p>` tag.

```
// Begin with '<p>' followed by any character and then end with '</p>'
var pattern = @"<p>.*</p>"; 
var regex = new Regex(pattern);

var sourceString = @"<p>Some Html... </p>\n<br />\n<p>The p section I want to remove</p>";

var matchCollection = regex.Matches(sourceString);
if(matchCollection.Count > 0)
{
    sourceString.Replace(matchCollection[matchCollection.Count - 1].Value, string.Empty);
}
```